# error compiling susy2 with gulp

Tags: gulp-sass, susy

I have a very simple gulp based test environment using only sass and the susy2 gem - no compass because compass is no longer a dependency of susy 2

The error i'm getting is

```
...sass/susy/language/susy/settings:8:error: error reading values after container
```

line 8 of the problem file, susy's settings is as follows:

```
@include susy-defaults((
  container: auto, <- line 8
  math: fluid,
  output: float,
  container-position: center,
  gutter-position: after,
  global-box-sizing: content-box,
  debug: (
    image: hide,
    color: rgba(#66f, .25),
    output: background,
    toggle: top right,
    inspect: false,
  ),
));
```

I'm using sass version 3.4, which should support the sass maps syntax, and gulp-sass version 0.7.3. along with susy 2.1.3.

Any idea why im getting this error?

Comment: Every get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update SASS to later than 3.3.  Current version of SASS as of this writing is 3.4.1 Selective Steve.  Type sass -v in your terminal (assuming OSX) to see what version of SASS you are currently on.

Comment: `gulp-sass` is not using `sass` for compiling, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`gulp-sass` is actually a wrapper around Node-sass, which again is a library
that provides binding for Node.js to libsass, the C version of the popular
stylesheet preprocessor, Sass.

It allows you to natively compile .scss files to css at incredible speed and
automatically via a connect middleware.

As this [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) page says:

> "..The libsass library is not currently at feature parity with the 3.2 Ruby Gem
>   that most Sass users will use, and has **little-to-no support for 3.3 syntax**.
>   While we try our best to maintain feature parity with libsass, we can not
>   enable features that have not been implemented in libsass yet."

So it **does not matter** which version of `sass` you have installed,
because `gulp-sass` is not using it.

The problem that arises with `susy2` is that of, `libsass` currently not
supporting some of features `susy2` exposes.

The way I resolved this issue, was using
[gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass) instead of
`gulp-sass`, which is slower but more feature-rich. And will work with `Susy2`.